# I uninstalled openssh-client and all my snap application have been erased

Tags: 18.04, gui, snap, openssh

I uninstalled openssh-client and i didn't see that another apps were uninstalled too. Now all my snap app like Reemina, atom, etc (all snap app that i've installed with ubuntu software gui) were deleted.
Now i installed snapd but i can't search snap apps with Ubuntu Software GUI.

Comment: `snapd` has a depends rule on `openssh-client` so it had to be removed; https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/snapd   Why did you remove openssh-client?  (*prior to removal [depending on how you removed] you are given a list of what will be removed; why did you -y or YES remove it*)

Comment: You can put back the missing deb packages with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^`. This will put back `snapd` `gnome-software-plugin-snap` and whatever else got removed.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me